# How to secure Titan - Elasticsearch connection with ssl/tls?

Tags: elasticsearch, titan

In order to comply with our company security policy, we need secure connection between Titan and Elasticsearch. After searching quiet a bit, this is the most helpful information I found - http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/0.5.1/elasticsearch.html#_secure_elasticsearch

Specifically,

> There are a couple of ways to approach security on the native "transport" protocol port:
>
> 1. Tunnel ES’s native "transport" protocol.
>      This approach can be implemented with SSL/TLS tunneling (for instance via stunnel), a VPN, or SSH port forwarding.
> 2. Add a firewall rule that allows only trusted clients to connect on Elasticsearch’s native protocol port

#2 is not an option for us because the data will not be encrypted while in motion.

I am not too familiar with ssl tunneling. So, my questions are: Does ssl tunneling help the data in motion to be encrypted? Is there any other solution to secure Titan/Elasticsearch connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ssh` tunneling simply refers to transmitting traffic from one port through the `ssh` encrypted protocol and making it appear elsewhere. This way the applications continue to think the traffic is unencrypted, but in fact it is encrypted over the network. A fairly involved explanation can be found here: https://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/ssh-tunnelling-explained/

You'd have to maintain a permanent `ssh` tunnel, which is fairly easily accomplished with a script that reconnects in case of failure, and by using the `ServerAliveInterval` [keep-alive option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3026/what-do-the-options-serveraliveinterval-and-clientaliveinterval-in-sshd-conf).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. the linked article is also very useful. So far I couldn't find any other ways to secure titan/elasticsearch connection. Please respond if anybody knows that part.